# ffmpeg keep all video metadata

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata

I have a video with incorrect video metadata which is messing up the color. Here is the original video's stream 0:0 Metadata:

```
Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc (Main 10) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p10le(pc), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1808 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Video Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : \013DOVI Coding
    Side data:
      DOVI configuration record: version: 1.0, profile: 5, level: 3, rpu flag: 1, el flag: 0, bl flag: 1, compatibility id: 0
```

Here is the code that didn't work:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i cover.jpg -disposition:0 attached_pic -map 1 -map 0 -vcodec copy -map_metadata 0 -acodec aac -b:a 512k -c:s mov_text output.mp4
```

Here is the result:

```
  Duration: 01:50:24.42, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2326 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc (Main 10) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p10le(pc), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1808 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 512 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
  Stream #0:3: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 500x750 [SAR 144:144 DAR 2:3], 90k tbr, 90k tbn (attached pic)
```

Stream 0:0 `handler_name` has changed from `Video Media Handler` to `VideoHandler` and the side data is lost. I've have other media that have a string of text in the `handler_name` which is also lost when recoding. The end result is my media players no longer recognize the video as HDR and I get purple people.

How can I keep the video's metadata?

Comment: Can you please share a short part of the original video (share using Google Drive for example)? What video player are you using? What is the version of FFmpeg? Can you reproduce the issue with a simplified command: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map 0 -c copy -map_metadata 0 output.mp4`?